# What data determines the homotopy fiber of a map?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, cw-complexes

Consider a mapof (pointed) CW complexes $f:F\to E$, and a fibration $p:E\to B$. What data is necessary to say if $f$ is equivalent to the inclusion of the fiber $f':F'\to E$?

Clearly $F$ should be homotopic to $F'$, and the composition $p\circ f$ is nullhomotopic. For example, one can map $\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb{R}$ by sending everything to $0$, then map $\mathbb R$ to the circle $\mathbb S^1$ according to the usual exponential. This is not the usual fiber (the copy of the integers in $\mathbb R$) but there is a homotopy between them (send $n$ from zero to $n$ at $n$ times unit speed).

Are these necessary conditions sufficient?

Comment: The fact that $p$ is a fibration is sufficient to guarantee that it's fibre $F=p^{-1}(\ast)$ and homotopy fibre $W_p$ are homotopy equivalent. The equivalence is canonical; just map $F\rightarrow W_p$, $e\mapsto(e,\ell_\ast)$, where $\ell_ast$ is the constant loop in $B$. The inverse is not canonical, but easy to produce (here is where the fibration part kicks in).

Comment: You might be looking for the universal property of fibers, which gives a characterization of $F \to E$.